# How to display multiple ag-grid using react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to use ag-grid with react making use of [this example](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-react-example)
(src-standard)

I'm new to this. could anybody tell me how do I display two grids on the same page. Do I just make changes in myApp.jsx (say, if I want to display the same grid twice only).